# Register different types of data

Tags: java

My task is to classify sentences with rappoort its weight.

I would have to regroup three types of data. I registered each type of data in a table, then I put it in an other table in order to have a table like this:

```
  Sentence      Weight      Class
  sentence1     0.342       classe1
  sentence2     0.231       classe2
  sentence3     0.535678    classe3
```

I made the following program:

```
String table1[]={"sentenc1","sentenc2","sentenc3"};
double table2[]={0.342,0.231,0.535678};
String table3[]={"classe1","classe2","classe3"};


Object [][] table= new Object[10][10]; 
int i=0;                
for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
{
    table[j][i]=table1[j];
}                
i=1;
for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
{
    table[j][i]=table2[j];
}
i=2;
for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
{
    table[j][i]=table3[j];
}
for(int k=0; k<3;k++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
    {
     System.out.println("table["+k+"]["+j+"]="+table[k][j]);
    }

}
```

Is it a good way or It has problems? Are there other method?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with this data, how you're going to access it, etc. We cannot answer correctly without knowing that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: No, I want you to give me another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An improvement could be to execute only one `for` statement, which will make it faster. Take into account that this is only useful if you previously know (as it looks like in this case) the number of tables you have. If not, you should add a nested for.

```
Object [][] table= new Object[10][10];                
for(int j=0; j<3;j++) {
    table[j][0]=table1[j];
    table[j][1]=table2[j];
    table[j][2]=table3[j];
}
```

The representation of the table is a method that can be called later without having to build the table again so you could create a new method called

```
public showTable() {
   for(int k=0; k<3;k++) {
       for(int j=0; j<3;j++) {
            System.out.println("table["+k+"]["+j+"]="+table[k][j]);
       }
   }
}
```

If you will never want to display the table again you can create the table and at the same time display it using the nested `for` of the method `showTable()`